# Getting posts from 9gag Api

Tags: r, get, httr2

I would like to download posts through the 9gag.com Api, which apparently exists but isn't documented anywhere. If you check this link in your browser, you will get a json response: https://9gag.com/v1/tag-posts/tag/wtf/type/fresh

So using `httr2` this should be easy. However:

```r
library(httr2)
req <- request("https://9gag.com/v1/tag-posts/tag/samantha/type/fresh")

req_dry_run(req)
#> GET /v1/tag-posts/tag/wtf/type/fresh HTTP/1.1
#> Host: 9gag.com
#> User-Agent: httr2/0.1.1 r-curl/4.3.2 libcurl/7.82.0
#> Accept: */*
#> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd

result <- req_perform(req) 
#> Error: HTTP 403 Forbidden.
```

I checked the network tab in Firefox Inspect and copied the GET request that is sent when I enter the URL:

```
curl 'https://9gag.com/v1/tag-posts/tag/wtf/type/fresh' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: ts1=456f0f77f4669644e64d425b5f7ad509ba4f2385; ____ri=1792; ____lo=DE' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Fri, 18 Mar 2022 11:04:32 GMT' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'TE: trailers'
```

Looks rather similar, except for the headers. So let's try with all these headers:

```
req <- request("https://9gag.com/v1/tag-posts/tag/samantha/type/fresh") %>% 
  req_headers(
    'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
    'Accept' = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language' = 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding' = 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection' = 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie' = 'ts1=456f0f77f4669644e64d425b5f7ad509ba4f2385; ____ri=1792; ____lo=DE',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' = '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest' = 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode' = 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site' = 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User' = '?1',
    'If-Modified-Since' = 'Fri, 18 Mar 2022 03:03:44 GMT',
    'Cache-Control' = 'max-age=0',
    'TE' = 'trailers'
  )

result <- req_perform(req)
#> Error: HTTP 403 Forbidden.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Unfortunately, the request is still turned down. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Your code works on my device, so it might be an issue not with your code but with your setup

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I tried it on different machines and through a vpn and it did not work. But it works fine on rstudio.cloud, so it's not a problem of the code, but I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Something weird I found as well - when I used the ubiquitous `requests` module in Python, got turned down. But the exact same request when I sent through a lower level module called `urllib`, it worked! Later I found a tool which could do this for me - https://randompearls.com/reference/tools/9gag-media-downloader?s=som